# AppleScript - Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found """

Tags: applescript

I am a beginner in AppleScript and I am trying to code a script that will write data into a list directly from a Numbers table.

So I coded this function:

```
on readTableABC(sheetName)
    set readTable to {}
    
    tell table "Table 1" of sheetName 
        set rowCellCount to count of cells of column "A"
        tell column "B"
            repeat with i from 2 to rowCellCount
                set the end of readTable to value of cell i
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
    
    return readTable
end readTableABC
```

sheetName will actually take the sheet name of the Numbers file.

When I compile, I get an error which says:

> Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found """ .

And the cursor shows this character:
[Character pointed out by the compiler][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUqxa.png

Would you have any idea where the mistake would be?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Nicolas

Comment: In order for the scripting terminology from the Numbers application to be used, they need to be included in a `tell application "Numbers"` statement, or a `use application "Numbers"` statement needs to be declared.

Comment: Thanks a lot, red_menace. I added "tell application "Numbers"" in the function and it now works perfectly.

Comment: Please post the relevant info as a formal answer, and accept it, so this issue will be flagged as "answered". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by red_menace:
In order for the scripting terminology from the Numbers application to be used, they need to be included in a tell application "Numbers" statement, or a use application "Numbers" statement needs to be declared.

Comment: Nicolas, Welcome to Stack Overflow, As comments can get deleted please make your answer stand by itself and include the now working code in your answer, as it will make it easier to see the difference between what wasn't working and what is working. Thanks.